# Group custom post types by taxonomy in timber (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy, timber

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to group a collection of post with the same taxonomy "year" attached to them in Wordpress, without using a separate archive template.

I Finally managed to get it to work with Wordpress, but now I want to translate this to timber, and I just can't seem to be able to do so. Can anyone give me some pointers?

**This is the working wordpress code**

```
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ex_terms = get_terms( 'exhibition-year','orderby=name&order=desc' );

foreach ( $ex_terms as $ex_term ) {
    $member_group_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'exhibition',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'exhibition-year',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $ex_term->slug ),
                'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            ),
            'meta_query'        => array(
                array(
                'key'           => 'date_end',
                'compare'       => '<',
                'value'         => $date_now,
                'type'          => 'DATETIME'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    if($ex_term->slug <= date('Y')){
    ?>
        <h2><?php echo $ex_term->name; ?></h2>
        <ul>
        <?php
        if ( $member_group_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $member_group_query->have_posts() ) : $member_group_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><?php echo the_title(); ?></li>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
        // Reset things, for good measure
        $member_group_query = null;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

The desired outcome should look something similar to this, I'm only displaying the titles. But it should contain the entire postdata.

**The desired outcome**
[image]

I've looked into:

https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-post/
https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber-postquery/
and
https://timber.github.io/docs/reference/timber/#get-terms

Please help, it's driving me insane :)

Answer (score 1):

Two changes to your query,

- Current timestamp in meta query
- Converting to `integer` type before comparing it with current year

  $current = current_time( 'timestamp' );
  $ex_terms = get_terms( 'exhibition-year', 'orderby=name&order=desc' );

  foreach ( $ex_terms as $ex_term ):

  ```
  $member_group_query = new WP_Query(
      array(
          'post_type' => 'exhibition',
          'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'exhibition-year',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => array( $ex_term->slug ),
                  'operator' => 'IN'
              )
          ),
          'meta_query'        => array(
              array(
                  'key'           => 'date_end',
                  'compare'       => '<',
                  'value'         => $current
              )
          )
      )
  );

  if( (int)$ex_term->slug <= date('Y')):

      echo '<h2>'.$ex_term->name.'</h2>';
      echo '<ul>';

      if ( $member_group_query->have_posts() ) : 

          while ( $member_group_query->have_posts() ) : $member_group_query->the_post();

              echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';

          endwhile; 

      endif;

      echo '</ul>';

  endif;

  $member_group_query = null;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ```

  endforeach;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually no, you did some minor code cleaning. The question remains how I can recreate this code in timberwp

Answer (score 0):

@CKDT this is untested, but here's a drive-by re-write in Timber...

### PHP

```
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$ex_terms = Timber::get_terms( 'exhibition-year','orderby=name&order=desc' );

foreach ( $ex_terms as &$ex_term ) {
    $member_group_query = Timber::get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'exhibition',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'exhibition-year',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( $ex_term->slug ),
            'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'meta_query'        => array(
            array(
            'key'           => 'date_end',
            'compare'       => '<',
            'value'         => $date_now,
            'type'          => 'DATETIME'
            )
        )
    ));
    $ex_term->events = $member_group_query;
    if( $ex_term->slug <= date('Y') ){
        $ex_term->past = true;
    }
}
$context['ex_terms'] = $ex_terms;
Timber::render('my-file.twig', $context);
```

### Twig File

```
{% for term in ex_terms %}
    {% if term.past %}
        <h2>{{ term.name }}</h2>
        <ul>
        {% for post in term.events %}
            <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul> 
{% endfor %}
```